# Select CASE and field name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sas

Can you create column name dynamically with a case statement? Such as (from a previous post I saw just so you can see I did look first);

```
SELECT   
    ProductNumber, Name, 
    CASE 
       WHEN Name = 'Gary' THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    End AS ProductNumber + 'Mfg item - not for resale'
FROM 
    Production.Product;
```

I know the example seems very odd, but I have a project where I need several pieces of information contained in rows converted to columns based on criteria I use in the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Column names need to be literals, period.  You can do this with Dynamic SQL but if you need dynamic column names you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:tsql] and [tag:sas]?  Those are two different languages unrelated to each other.  What are you doing this in?

Comment: I can't even picture what you're trying to do... Say that query returns 20 rows and 10 of them aren't for resale.  How do you expect the column header to support that?

Comment: If you had provided a sample data set, it would have been more clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Or a sample results...

Comment: You need a column name created dynamically or a column value?!

Comment: No, not without dynamic sql

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible because in your theoretical answer you'd have a different column name for each row. You cannot do anything like this in a set based solution.

Dynamic SQL would only work if you did it in some sort of cursor based solution with unique tables for each resultset and (as was said in the question comments) if you're doing this you're doing something wrong.

For whatever you're doing you're probably best off returning the desired column name as a column called something like `[ColumnName]` and then transforming this in whatever project you're using it for.

Comment: Thanks guys... that is what I thought, but wanted to check with those more knowledgeable than I. Thanks again!